# PHP Function won't work on form submission

Tags: php, youtube-api

I've been working on a function to get the ID from a YouTube URL. The function works, which;

```
Function getYouTubeID($URL){
    $YouTubeCheck = preg_match('![?&]{1}v=([^&]+)!', $URL . '&', $Data);
    If($YouTubeCheck){
        $VideoID = $Data[1];
        Echo $VideoID;
    }
}
```

The only part that isn't working for me is when I'm trying to call it on form submission;

```
<form action="<?php If(IsSet($_POST['submit'])){ 
              If(!$_POST['video_id'] == NULL){
                  $VideoID = getYouTubeID($_POST['video_url']); 
                  Header('Location: /watch?v='.$VideoID); }} ?>" method="POST">
```

I can call the function in it's own file (test.php);

```
Function getYouTubeID($URL){
    $YouTubeCheck = preg_match('![?&]{1}v=([^&]+)!', $URL . '&', $Data);
    If($YouTubeCheck){
        $VideoID = $Data[1];
        Echo $VideoID;
    }
}

getYouTubeID('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=example');
```

And that would return "example," however, as mentioned before, I can't call it through form submission, or even by trying to include it (include 'filewiththefunction.php').

Any help is greatly appreciated, and thanks for your time.

Comment: `<?php If(IsSet($_POST['submit'])){ ... ?>` doesn't seem to output anything. The action field in a <form> needs to be set to the url that the browser sends the POST information to. Also, `header()` must appear before any output to the browser, otherwise it does not do anything.

Comment: @AlexGittemeier Hmm, I've changed the code up a bit, following your examples, and it's gotten me a little further so thanks :)

Comment: Anytime :) Also, Sudhir provided an answer along the lines of my comment, and it spells it out better than I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

placing if condition for checking POST in form action wont do anything, you should be doing something like following:

**Basic Example**

```
form action="someting.php">
<input type="text" name="video_url" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="Show" value="Show" />
</form>
```

then in **something.php**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $VideoID = getYouTubeID($_POST['video_url']); 
 header('Location: /watch?v='.$VideoID); 
}
?>
```